How to change hamburger color in footer
the I need to change the color of the hamburger icon in the footer of my website. Here's what This is the HTML code that includes the item:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" aria-label="Footer menu (NL)">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar112" aria-controls="navbar112" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Schakelen navigatie">
        <span class="icon-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar112">
        <ul id="footermenu" class="mod-menu mod-list nav ">
<li class="nav-item item-122"><a href="/nl/anbi">ANBI</a></li><li class="nav-item item-123"><a href="/nl/jaarverslagen">Jaarverslagen</a></li><li class="nav-item item-124"><a href="/nl/beleid">Beleid</a></li><li class="nav-item item-427"><a href="/nl/donateursbelangen">DonateursBelangen</a></li></ul>
    </div>
</nav>

I've tried adding to CSS custom file:
.navbar-toggler {

        color:#fff;
        }

I did also try !Important  but that didn't help either.
In Inspect mode I can see that this is the Bootstrap 4 CSS code that determines the current color:
.navbar-toggler{
color: var(--bs-navbar-color);

ps: I use the Helix framework by Joomshaper as a template, so adding another class is not an option I guess.
